# Копия AUTO_INCREMENT в соседнюю ячейку при INSERT в MySQL

Tags: mysql

Возникла необходимость, когда создается новая запись делать копию ячейки `id` которая имеет свойства `AUTO_INCREMENT`, в ту же таблицу, но в другую ячейку.

```
INSERT INTO my_table SET text = 'any more text', date = NOW(), position = ??
```

Нужна эта штука для того чтобы формировать статическую сортировку, другими словами формировать последовательность вывода данных согласно поля `position` который по сути должен содержать данные поля (ячейки) `id`, но только когда вставили данные.

Comment: достаточно брать максимальный position  + 1 и никак не привязываться на AUTO_INCREMENT

Comment: В insert вы этого не укажете, вам надо сделать триггер на таблицу который будет копировать значение

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, не соглашусь, т.к. потом нужно писать мудреную сортировку, а вот Mike говорит, дело, но думал есть способы проще...

Comment: "надо сделать триггер". И дальше пошли фокусы - в before insert автоинкремента ещё нет, а в after insert mysql не даст сделать update той же самой таблицы (или уже всё-таки можно?). Навскидку нормальных путей не помню.

Comment: Триггер не вариант, это желательно сделать по средствам запроса.

Comment: @Shnur я всех подробностей не знаю, что впоследствии ты делаешь. Однако пока я не вижу в чем могут быть проблемы с этим, даже не смотря на какую-то там абстрактную мудреную сортировку

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, это плюс один запрос перед вставкой, а хотелось бы его избежать, если я правильно Вас понял.

Comment: @Shnur вполне может быть подзапросом в том же запросе. `position = (SELECT ....)` ...........................`плюс один запрос перед вставкой, а хотелось бы его избежать` - но ведь триггер тоже инициирует доп. запрос.

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, спасибо, думал, что все же есть лазейки в MySQL, но похоже все как обычно ))))) Буду делать старыми дедовскими способами.